# Edit home page variable value from iframe in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, web, iframe

I have a index.php page that has following body

```
<?php
$uploaded = 0;
$slectionsize = 0;
?>
inside body of html i have
<?php
if($uploaded == 0){
echo '<div class="content1"><iframe scrolling="no" src="uploadmain.php" height="650" width="200%" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" title="Embedded post"></iframe></div>';
}
if($uploaded == 1){
echo "next iframe";
}
?>
```

so src of iframe uploadmain.php does file upload,
after upload it echo success, Look at my uploadmain.php

```
      if(empty($errors)==true){
     move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$file_name);
     echo "Success";
  }else{
     print_r($errors);
  }
```

So i want that after file upload my $uploaded variable becomes 1,  and then my page refreshed and second iframe is displayed instead of first iframe and i also want to fetch the $file_name variable to home so that i can store it in database

Answer (score 1):

You don't need this `$uploaded` variable in your main page.

An iframe is like a browser inside your webpage. All you need to do, to jump to the next iframe, is command a jump, inside the first iframe, to go to the next iframe.

You could use this in the first iframe:

```
header("Refresh:0; url=iframe2.php");
```

Note that you will need to do this before any other output is generated by the first iframe, otherwise you will get a *"headers already sent"* error.

Another way to load the second iframe is:

```
readfile("iframe2.php");
```

again, inside the first frame. This will, however, not execute any PHP code.

Note that the code in your question might be incomplete, and my solution might not work for you. I can only answer the question that is there.